# How to escape content in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using webpack template for my vuejs project (vuejs: version 2). I would like to know how can I render my content escaped (other way than `v-html`) :

Note that the `message` contains some `<a>` tags like : `These is my website <a href="https://google.com">link</a>`.

Like in handlebars, I want to use something like :

`<p>{{{ message }}}</p>` and `<p>{{{ message | customFilter }}}</p>`.

I've tried the first option but it doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work with triple mustaches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive

So it sounds like you can't do it with the mustache-syntax.

If you want to [combine filters with directive bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Filters), use a computed property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Patrick. Exactly the 3 braces are deprecated in vue 2... But how can I use filters inside of `v-html` please ?

Comment: I think "computed" it's not a better way for me because I have a dynamic content in different components... I created a custom directive to resolve this. Thanks @Patrick for your assistance.

Answer (score 8):

I know that is not what OP wants, but for Googlers:

```
<span v-html="`{{ hey }}`"></span>
```

Comment: 2021: Syntax that worked for me is: `<span v-html="hey"></span>`. Oh Lawd, why did thou maketh front-end development trendy? It's horrendous.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid using `v-html`(for security reasons). In this case you can use `CSS`, with `content` property, check this example:

```css
span.open:before {
  content: '{{';
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
span.close:after {
  content: '}}';
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="open"></span>hey<span class="close"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right...
avoid v-html, I guess...

```
data() {
        return {

            ಠ: '{{',
            ಭ: '}}',
```

then this works...
I hate this stuff though.

```
<template>
    smaller docker ps <br>
    docker ps --format 'table{{ಠ}}.ID{{ಭ}}\t{{ಠ}}.Status{{ಭ}}\t{{ಠ}}.Image{{ಭ}}\t{{ಠ}}.Names{{ಭ}}'
</template>
```

will print

```
smaller docker ps
docker ps --format 'table{{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}'
```

O...yeah...
ಭ and ಠ can be replaced by any variable-name that makes sense to you.